# Entropic Value-at-Risk for a Normally Distributed random variable

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable, risk

I have been reading about the [Entropic Value-at-Risk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropic_value_at_risk) measure and its applications. The definition of this risk measure is as follows [1,2]:

$${\displaystyle {\text{EVaR}}_{1-\alpha }(X):=\inf _{z>0}\left\{z^{-1}\ln \left({\frac {M_{X}(z)}{\alpha }}\right)\right\}.}$$

Where $M_{X}(z)$ is the moment-generating function and $\alpha$ is the confidence level.

I am interested in applying this measure on a random variable ${\displaystyle X\sim N(\mu ,\sigma ^{2}),}$

Both the wikipedia page and the [original paper](http://cloud.politala.ac.id/politala/Jurnal/JurnalTI/Jurnal%2007/Journal%20of%20Optimization%20Theory%20and%20Applications/art-3A10.1007-2Fs10957-011-9968-2.pdf) give the solution for a confidence level $1-\alpha$ simply as:

$${\displaystyle {\text{EVaR}}_{1-\alpha }(X)=\mu +\sigma {\sqrt {-2\ln \alpha }}.}$$

I tried to arrive at this solution from the definition above using the moment-generating function of the Normal Distribution but I don't know how to go about it. After a few simplifications of the expression, at which step would one take out the z or replace it with a constant value.

I also tried to equate both expressions and solve for z to get an idea about the solution without any success.

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropic_value_at_risk
2. Ahmadi-Javid, Amir (2012). "Entropic value-at-risk: A new coherent risk measure". Journal of Optimization Theory and Applications. 155 (3): 1105–1123. doi:10.1007/s10957-011-9968-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Normal$(\mu,\sigma^2)$ mgf is

$$\log \phi(z;\mu,\sigma) = \mu z + \sigma^2 \frac{z^2}{2}.$$

Thus you need to minimize the function defined on the positive real numbers as

$$\begin{aligned}
f(z) &= z^{-1}\left(\mu z + \sigma^2 \frac{z^2}{2} - \log\alpha\right)\\
&= \mu + \sigma\sqrt{-2\log\alpha} + \left(\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{2}}\sqrt z - \sqrt{-\log\alpha}\frac{1}{\sqrt z}\right)^2.
\end{aligned}\tag{*}$$

(The second line is nothing but elementary algebra.)

Here is a typical plot on log-log axes:

[image]

Because the squared term at the right of $(*)$ cannot be negative, and actually equals zero at values

$$z^* = \sqrt{-\frac{\sigma^2}{2\log \alpha}},$$

the positive square root $z^*$ is the unique global *minimum* (not just an infimum), with

$$f(z^*) = \mu + \sigma\sqrt{-2\log\alpha} .$$

*This* was the "step [where] would one take out the $z$ or replace it with a constant value."

Comment: After I asked my question I figured out I had to find a minimum, however I spent time calculating the derivative and equating it to 0 trying to find the minimum. Your rewriting of $f(z)$ makes things way clearer.

Comment: If you would like the details of the calculus approach, see the first version of this post ;-)  (It's available by clicking through the "edited ... ago" link at the bottom of the post.)

Comment: @whuber, could you also include the r implementation? Thanks.

Comment: @Max It's merely a graph of $f$ for any choice of $\alpha,$ $\mu,$ and $\sigma,$ with custom labels on the axes: use `curve(..., log="xy")`.